# Object inside response body for http error

Tags: angular, http, error-handling, response

I'm trying to figure out how to access an object inside response body when an error occurs during an http call.
My backend fills the http response with a detailed custom error object like this:

```
{
    "title": "UNAUTHORIZED WEB",
    "message": "Sorry, but seems that your access is denied or not valid anymore."
}
```

if I call this endpoint and try to read the error doing like the following:

```js
    this.http.get<any>(URL).subscribe(
        () => { ... stuff ... },
        (error) => console.log(error)
    )
```

it just prints the code, not even an HttpErrorResponse object, though inspecting the network I can clearly see that inside response there is such object. How can I access the object inside the response?

Comment: Can you give more details of what currently is printed to your console, on what HttpErrorCode you are getting this, and did you try hitting the url from another client like postman(did it work).

Comment: what is the status code of api when you are getting the response?

Comment: the console prints in this example '401' and nothing else. Using postman I see the response error body as well. What I'm trying to achieve is to read this error response body from within angular app and print the custom message on screen, since each endpoint has its unique error description and I don't want to replicate them

Comment: check my answer below.

Comment: and are you using any httpinterceptors in your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are receiving this object with status code 200 you will never get it in error callback of subscribe. But if code is something like 500, 400 or so which are real http error codes.

you should be able to access with error.body in your callback.

Comment: Status code represents the correct status code. For instance if it's forbidden is 403, if there was some problem evaluating the request it's 500 and so on. Unfortunately if I print error.body I get nothing, but if I inspect the network, under response tab it is there

Comment: are you using any httpinterceptors in your project?

Comment: yes, I use one to append authorization headers, and one to print to console the full http url and response

Comment: Check if there is any interceptor, modifying the response. Or if you have any custom http layer you have written on top of http client. check there if you are modifying the error response.

Comment: thanks for the advice, looks like my authorization interceptor somehow modifies the response, thanks again to helping me figure out this